# How come iAd events are never fired

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

So I followed some tutorials on how to integrate iAds, and finally managed to get it to work, but only visually that is. What I mean is that I see the ad on my iPhone app, I can click on it and see the test info, but none of the events were ever fired. Below is my code for the event handlers, is there anything I should check out?

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"--- bannerViewDidLoadAd ---");
    NSLog(@"self.isBannerVisible: %@", self.isBannerVisible);

    if(!self.isBannerVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        self.banner.frame = CGRectOffset(self.banner.frame, 0.0, self.bannerVisibleY);
        self.header.frame = CGRectOffset(self.header.frame, 0.0, self.headerWithBannerY);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.isBannerVisible = YES;
    }
}


- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner 
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"--- bannerView ---");
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"self.isBannerVisible: %@", self.isBannerVisible);

    if(self.isBannerVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        self.banner.frame = CGRectOffset(self.banner.frame, 0.0, self.bannerHiddenY);
        self.header.frame = CGRectOffset(self.header.frame, 0.0, self.headerNoBannerY);

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.isBannerVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the ADBannerView's delegate?

Comment: I do in the header of the file:

@interface QuickRatioCalculatorFreeViewController:UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
 ADBannerView *banner;
}

Comment: That just declares that this ViewController conforms to the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol.  You still need to actually set the delegate property of the ADBannerView.  If you are using a .nib, control drag from the banner to File's Owner and select delegate.

Comment: Ah! This is what was missing, thanks so much!

Comment: Ok I posted as answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting  in the header only declares that this ViewController conforms to the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol. You still need to actually set the delegate property of the ADBannerView. If you are using a .nib, control drag from the banner to File's Owner and select delegate.

Generally if you're delegate callbacks aren't getting called, this is the problem.